# JS при открытии файла PHP его не видит или еще что-то выдает ошибки, как исправить?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

При работе на локальном сервере все шло отлично(перенес код на Wordpress случились ошибки).
Мой JS скрипт не может обратиться к PHP скрипту ,который работает как счетчик. Прописывал разные пути (3 файла лежат в одной папке) ничего не получилось. Код ниже.
Ошибка в FireFox:

> Ошибка синтаксического анализа XML: неопределённая сущность Адрес: http://votrrrrbs.ru/ClicksCounterVlad_File.php?go=yes Строка 14, символ 1:

Ошибка в Chrom:
Ругается на эту строчку `http_request.send();` Сама ошибка:

> GET http://votrrrrbs.ru/ClicksCounterVlad_File.php?go=yes 404 (Not Found)ClicksCounterVlad_Script_Body.js?ver=1:19 doclick(index):253 onclick

Код:

```
function doclick(){ 
    var vid = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
    vid.play();
    var http_request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
    http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');}
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
    try {http_request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
    catch (e) {
    try {http_request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
    catch (e) {}
    }
    }
    if (!http_request) {return false;}
 http_request.onreadystatechange = function() {  alertContents(http_request); };
    http_request.open('GET','/ClicksCounterVlad_File.php?go=yes', true);
    http_request.send();
    }

function pauseVid(){
    var vid = document.getElementById("myAudio"); 
    vid.pause();
}
```

По идее этот скрипт при нажатии кнопки воспроизводит аудио и открывает PHP скрипт, но этого не случается консоль показывает что эта ошибка где-то здесь:

```
http_request.open('GET','/ClicksCounterVlad_File.php?go=yes', true);
    http_request.send();
```

Код PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['go']=='yes'){
$file = fopen('clicks.txt','a+');
$put = file_put_contents('ClicksCounterVlad_File_numbers.txt',((int) file_get_contents('ClicksCounterVlad_File_numbers.txt')) + 1);
}
?>
```

Он при открытии файла читает содержимое и добавляет 1.

Comment: Проверьте имя файла скрипта. Если локально проверяли под windows, то она не обращает внимания на регистр. При переносе на linux хостинг могут вылезти ошибки "файл не найден" если в реальности ClicksCounterVlad_File.php имеет другой регистр в имени файла

Comment: Проверил и переименовал,не помогло.

Comment: Если просто в браузере открыть  http://votrrrrbs.ru/ClicksCounterVlad_File.php то что выводит?

Comment: Ничего не найдено

Comment: http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){alertContents(http_request); };
так же выдает ошибку

Comment: На локальном сервере тестировалось под таким же вордпрессом? Может на проде нет нужных маршрутов?

Comment: На локальном тестировалось на голом скелете в 3 файла счетчик PHP,файл в который он записывал и сам скрипт JS  на OpenServer.

Comment: Кстати если перейти на страницу ошибки в фаерфокс выдает эту строку
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Что-то там &raquo; Лента" href="http://votrrrrbs.ru/feed" />

Comment: Просто вордпресс ничего не знает о вашем файле. Надо создать ему ссылку в настройках https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: Спасибо,сейчас попробую.

Comment: К сожалению не могу прописать произвольную ссылку,сайт с большим контентом может что нибудь полететь,возможно как то еще заставить ворд пресс увидеть скрипт PHP?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov это не так. WordPress тут ни при чём. Настройка постоянных ссылок не нужна. Файлы с "прямым доступом" в WordPress работают.

Comment: У вас в какой папке лежит файл .php? Вы должны указать полный url к файлу через `http://ваш-сайт.ru/....` Конструкция типа `/ClicksCounterVlad_File.php` работать не может.

Comment: Работа с файлам на ВП?!! Для счётчика? О, ужас..

Comment: Ну подскажите как правильно)